# Vector graphics software for 10.1 netbooks with screen resolution 1024x600?

Tags: netbook, resolution, vector-graphics, image-editing, requirements

I have a netbook with 10.1 inch screen and resolution 1024x600, like most netbooks with that screen size.

I need to work with vector graphics (not bitmap like what photoshop deals with). 1024x768  is the requirement for Adobe Illustrator's resolution ([illustrator specs requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/tech-specs.html)). In other words they want XGA and higher.

Are there any alternatives? I am working under a windows OS, but I am willing to use Linux if a suitable solution exists with that OS.

EDIT:(or would I be better off trying to find a netbook with 10.1inch screens and a higher resolution, if they exist?)
EDIT2: removed the suggestion of paint.net

Comment: Paint.net is not even a vector graphics software AFAIK. What about InkScape? http://inkscape.org/index.php?lang=en

Comment: @Shiki, but it can do vector graphics at least, from what I understand.

Comment: Paint.net can't do vectors. It's for bitmap graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDN isn't a vector graphics programme - its pure raster and handles NO vector formats. It does seem to work on a 800x600 screen resolution - i turned down the resolution on the system i have it, and it isn't too bad.

Give [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/doc/index.php?lang=en) a shot - its a proper vector graphics software, handles adobe illustrator files and others. It installs and runs fine at 800x600, but with the small screensize/low resolution, you may need to tweak the UI somewhat however, else it might be somewhat cluttered

Comment: how come it still runs fine although the requirements state a higher size? What type of tweaking is needed? Did you find any particular difficulties on some features?

Comment: Well, presumably they decided not to check for it. I tested it on a 17 inch screen, and other than a big chunk of the screen being used for things that would usually be a smaller chunk of screen, i didn't see too many problems. I'm not a inkscape pro but i would guess the main issue would be the tiny screen ;p